# Doseq evaluates 1 x for every y. Is there any way to make it evaluate 1 x for 1 y and so on in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I wasn't really sure how to phrase the name of this thread, so if you can clarify it any, please do so.

My example code is this:

```
(doseq [x [1 2 3] y [3 2 1]] (println (str x y)))
```

The output of that code is:

```
13
12
11
23
22
21
33
32
31
nil
```

I understand that list comprehensions, and doseq both evaluate like this. Is there another way to do this, so that instead of 1 element of x being used for every element of y, and so on, 1 element of x is used with 1 element of y and so on, so that the output would instead be:

```
13
22
31
```

Sorry if I'm not phrasing this right, I just can't seem to put it in words right.

EDIT: I think you can do this in Haskell with list comprehensions and a language extension. ParallelListComps or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do

```
(doseq [[x y] (map vector [1 2 3] [3 2 1])] 
  (println (str x y)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(partition 2
  (interleave [1 2 3] [3 2 1]))
```

`interleave` yields a sequence of alternating elements from the given sequences and `partition` groups this sequence into sequences of `n` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is more succint:

```
 (doall (map println [1 2 3] [3 2 1]))
```